# How do I exit fullscreen mode in vmware fusion 5, Windows 8 guest?

Tags: windows-8, vmware-fusion

In VMWare Fusion 5, when I enter fullscreen mode in most operating systems (Including Windows 7) on a multi-monitor setup; a black bar appears on the left hand side of the screen allowing me to exit fullscreen:

[image: Fullscreen Bar]

This option does not exist when the guest is Windows 8. There don't seem to be any other options to easily exit fullscreen, including no "top" bar and no three finger swipe.

How do I exit fullscreen mode for VMWare in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shortcut <kbd>CMD + Ctrl + Enter</kbd> to exit the fullscreen-mode.